# mask can not moved and resize in PIXIJS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I want to manipulate masks in PIXIJS.
I wrote the code based on the official example. (https://pixijs.io/examples/#/masks/sprite.js).

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: $(window).innerWidth(),
    height: $(window).innerHeight(),
    backgroundColor: 0x000000,
    antialias: true,
    
});

app.stage.hitArea = app.screen;
app.stage.interactive = true;
const rect = new PIXI.Graphics().beginFill(0xff0000,1).drawRect(0,0, 500, 500).endFill();
const sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from('Assets/UI/play.png');
sprite.x = 250;
sprite.y = 250;
rect.mask = sprite;

app.stage.addChild(rect);
```

I moved sprite, but it did not move from (0,0). [this image shows the result of the execution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkUvy.png)
How do I move or resize the mask?
thank you.

PIXIJS:6.2.0
Running with webpack and babel.

Comment: `I moved sprite, but it did not move from (0,0)` - how do you moved it? Can you paste also that code?

Comment: I moved it to (250,250) as shown in the code above. However, the result is still (0,0).

Comment: Try two things: 1. Move `rect`. 2. See https://api.pixijs.io/tutorials/_basics/containers.html  - the part `Masking` and there `Add the mask as a child, so that the mask is positioned relative to its parent` - `maskContainer.addChild(mask);` - try doing similarly.

Comment: By adding the mask to the container, we were able to see the mask move.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes for adding the mask as a child to the container